# Multiscroll slide diagonally

Tags: javascript, php, css, scroll, slide

I want to make a vertical slide divided in two (with text on one side and an image on the other) but separated diagonally rather than vertically. In order to make myself better understood I am trying to obtain this effect (https://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/) in a diagonal way (see the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLfLJ.jpg)). I've been looking for javascript plugins but I haven't found anything yet.

If anyone can help me I would be grateful :)

Thank you,
Florian

Comment: I think that diagonal effect is just a css transformation

Comment: Hey thank you ! How I should do with css?

Comment: maybe [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) will help